# Split by columns of 2d list into new list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy, split

I have [the Thoracic Surgery dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Thoracic+Surgery+Data) from [the UCI dataset repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html).
A single line from this dataset looks like this:

```
DGN3,4.36,3.28,PRZ1,F,F,F,T,F,OC12,T,F,F,T,F,59,T
```

I have a script that reads these lines into a list of sublists:
Each sublist is a line in the file, containing some transformation of the data (mostly, just turning each element in the line into some numerical value; this part is not relevant to the problem)

Thus, each sublist looks like this:

```
[3.0, 4.36, 3.28, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 12.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,59.0, 1.0]
```

Now, what I would like to do is turn this list of sublists into two lists of sublists, where:

- the `i`th sublist of the first list contains everything but the last element of the `i`th sublist of the original list
- the `i`th sublist of the second list contains only the last element of the `i`th sublist of the original list.

For example, the row (sublist) shown above would be split into two sublists as follows:

```
[3.0, 4.36, 3.28, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 12.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,59.0]
[1.0]
```

Now, I know that I can do this very easily as follows:

```
features, classes = [], []
for subl in L:
    features.append(subl[:-1])
    classes.append([subl[-1]])
```

I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. Is there perhaps an itertools recipe or somthing out of numpy that would be better suited for this?

Comment: What version of Python? Isn't there some sort of new syntax for `a, *b, c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` which automatically assigns `b` as much as wasn't grabbed by `a` and `c`?

Comment: @mhlester: good question. I'm on 2.7, unfortunately. And I think you mean `a, *b, c = [1,2,3,4,5]` from python3?

Comment: yeah, I wasn't positive when that was introduced, but it's certainly not on 2.7. drat :(

Comment: (and yes the `b*` was just a typo)

Comment: I would be happy with the short and sweet code you have.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: I wouldn't. I have far too many rows and would much rather some form of optimized `reshape`-like magic (hence the reference to numpy). The alternative is to start throwing `multiprocessing` at this, which is more heavy lifting than I would like (hence the itertools recipes reference)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget have you looked at the pandas module?

Comment: @MrE: no I have not (been on my todo list for far too long). I'd appreciate any snippets of code you could throw at me

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm still learning to use it. Maybe post a subset of the data and what you're trying to get out of it and I (or someone who knows Pandas better) can advise.

Comment: @MrE: There is already an example of the data in my post and the expected output. Please let me know if that is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is already pretty much the best you can do in terms of processing the list `L`. You *could* shorten this into a zipped list comprehension to make it a one-liner but that won’t reduce its complexity:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20]]
>>> features, classes = zip(*[(s[:-1], [s[-1]]) for s in L])
>>> features
([1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8], [10, 11], [13, 14, 15, 16], [18, 19])
>>> classes
([5], [9], [12], [17], [20])
```

If the processing time of this really is an issue, you should think about doing these splits directly with your data transformation, so you don’t generate an intermediary format you won’t end up using anyway.

Comment: Sucks that there isn't a faster way. Looks like I'm going to have to throw multiprocessing at this. Thanks :)